# How to shift/change arabic unicode reference in ttf or otf font so it became latin unicode

Tags: text, fonts, webfonts, truetype, fontforge

Please help. 
I have arabic font (me_quran.ttf), it has glyph in unicode range U+0600..U+06FF (arabic unicode).

How to change me_quran.ttf so the glyph id or unicode reference is shifting and it can be use for latin unicode U+0041..etc. And still can use its ligatures or diacritics?

**Update**
My real problem is  there is some android webview that refuse to use **custom** arabic font, but ok for custom latin font. This has been question many times by others and still no right solution, and i cannot comment to their page question

Comment: [Why](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)? What difference will shifting the glyphs from their correct code points to the *wrong* code points make? Other than now being a bad font, obviously?

Comment: Because there is some android webview that refuse to use arabic font, but ok for latin font.

Comment: So the problem you're having is not "how to change the internal glyph mapping" but "I have a webview that's refusing to properly style this arabic text, what am I doing wrong". Ask about that, instead.

Comment: But there is a lot of question about that @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans and not one has solution for it. And i cannot comment to there page question (still new here), so i try to make a solution by asking another way. By the way do you have suggestion if my question similar to yours?

Comment: Change your question, and add code so it can be reproduced: how are you setting up your WebView, etc. (because webviews support unicode and opentype, so normal Arabic, with proper code, works quite well)

Comment: It is, it just cannot use the custom arabic font (not the embeded font). No special setting or code. I already read from other post from stackoverflow and google but the problem is the webview version below 4.2. Thank you for contributing.

Comment: Right, so that is information that [needs to be in your post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Give as much detail as possible, so people who are not you can understand the real problem, and all the things involved in it. Knowing which versions of Android is a problem for you is important: Android < 4.2 has amazingly broken webfont support. Even if you map the Arabic glyphs themselves to the latin block, none of the ligature functionality (which is incredibly important for arabic, to make sure initial, medial, and final forms are the right ones, etc) will work.